# How to use OnListItemClick action to open a new ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I have the following ListItem listener, which I want when I click in one of the list open up another list with different options.

```
public class MyList extends ListFragment {

    ...

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), AnotherList.class);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the other List I want it to open up when I picked the first option

```
public class AnotherList extends ListFragment {

    ArrayList<String> storage = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("Test", "Test"));
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, storage);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I get the following error message though

> 06-02 11:52:39.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1231):
>   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {.....}; have you declared this activity in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml?

Do I have declare `AnotherList` in my manifest file? Weird if I have to since I did not do that with my first ListFragment.

**UPDATE:**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.list_fragment, new AnotherList());
ft.commit();
```

**OLD main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:name="com.sanguosha.MyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**NEW working main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. should be the Activity to start fragment not other fragment
2. the snippet

   ```
   Intent newActivity = new Intent(v.getContext(), AnotherList.class);
   startActivity(newActivity);
   ```

is wrong. You have to use `startActivity` to start an Activity not a Fragment. For fragment you have to use a `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: It worked, however it did not replace the previous list, instead the new list overlapped. I updated my code with it

Comment: You should have a container managed by the Activity. The activity has to replace the container content.

Comment: It works now. I had to adjust the `main_activity.xml` layout. Which I'm not entirely sure why it was need. I updated my question with it

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about the `<fragment>` tag so I assumed it was needed when using fragments. But in this case it wasn't

Comment: You need a view where your fragment can put the resul of onCreateView. With the previously version you were nesting fragment. That is a bad thing